# How to satisfy this situation by using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a situation where I want to split events from a specific origin signal into two signals, one emitting events immediately and another emitting events with a 3 seconds delay. And rest of the origin events always emit a new event immediately. 
But if a new event arrives on the origin signal before the delayed event has been emitted, the delayed event should be discarded.

something like this
[image]

I map each the origin signal to **CS1(for immediately emitted events)**, and filter specific events of the origin signal to **CS2(for delayed emitted events)**.
[image]
[image]

Then I merge **CS1** and **CS2** into **CS3** which will not discard **S2**.

So, my question is how to discard or cancel S2, and how can I achieve this situation using RAC without using extra temporary variables?

**ReactiveCocoa 2.x** current code

```
RACSignal* origin = …    
RACSignal* CS1 = [origin map:^id _Nullable(id  _Nullable value) {
        return @(YES);
    }];
RACSignal* CS2 = [[[origin filter:^BOOL(id  _Nullable value) {
        return [RACSignal empty];
    }] delay:3] map:^id _Nullable(id  _Nullable value) {
        return @(NO);
    }];
RACSignal* CS3 = [RACSignal merge:@[CS1, CS2]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One remark unrelated to the actual question: `filter` should return a bool that is `YES` if the element should be sent and `NO` if the element should be filtered out.

To the actual question:

The solution to the problem is to use `takeUntil`. However, if you apply `takeUntil` directly to CS2, CS2 as a whole will be cancelled as soon as an event arrives on CS1.

The solution is to use `flatMap`, to build a new `RACSignal` for the delayed element and then use `takeUntil` on that inner signal.

I've split the single steps into multiple temporary signals only for clarity (I've also changed the `map` and `filter` so I could see better whats happening when trying my example, you should easily be able to use your correct functions there):

```
RACSignal* CS1 = [self.origin map:^id _Nullable(NSNumber * _Nullable value) {
  return value;
}];

RACSignal *filtered = [self.origin filter:^BOOL(NSNumber * _Nullable value) {
  return (value.integerValue % 2) == 0;
}];

RACSignal *delayed = [filtered flattenMap:^__kindof RACSignal * _Nullable(id  _Nullable value) {
  // Build a new signal that returns just this one value,
  // but delayed and only if no event arrives on CS1
  return [[[RACSignal return:value]
           delay:3]
          takeUntil:CS1];
}];

RACSignal* CS2 = [delayed map:^id _Nullable(NSNumber * _Nullable value) {
  return @(-value.integerValue);
}] ;


RACSignal* CS3 = [RACSignal merge:@[CS1, CS2]];
```

You can easily collapse this back into just two signals

```
RACSignal *CS2 = [[[self.origin filter:^BOOL(NSNumber * _Nullable value) {
  return (value.integerValue % 2) == 0;
}] flattenMap:^__kindof RACSignal * _Nullable(id  _Nullable value) {
  // Build a new signal that returns just this one value,
  // but delayed and only if no event arrives on CS1 before
  return [[[RACSignal return:value]
           delay:3]
          takeUntil:CS1];
}] map:^id _Nullable(NSNumber * _Nullable value) {
  return @(-value.integerValue);
}];
```

I've created [a sample project on github](https://github.com/iv-mexx/RACDelayedExample) to demonstrate the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very impressive answer. I have found another solution(CS2 return signal of signals then switchToLatest) but it just discard signals, mapping block is always processed. Your answer is much more elegant and optimized.

Comment: seems CS2 is never triggered @MeXx

Comment: Is it not? I built a small sample application sending values on `origin` via a button, and it worked in that example. Maybe you can show a bigger picture of your usecase?

Comment: I've created a small sample project: https://github.com/iv-mexx/RACDelayedExample